# CSS box-shadow properties - granular access to the various properties

Tags: jquery, css, box-shadow

Is there a way to access the seperate properties for box-shadow..

e.g.

I want to pull out the value of 'blur' and 'spread' separately, and set some sliders I have based on these values.

Is there some way to access these from the shorthand 'box-shadow' property

e.g.

box-shadow-spread
box-shadow-color,

ect.

I don't want to store a bunch of attributes on the node, just to track these values and setup controls.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the ole **pick_apart function**:

```
function pick_apart(img_id) {
    hold_res={}
    ss = $('#' + img_id).css('box-shadow')
    hold_res['color'] = ss.substring(ss.lastIndexOf("r"),ss.lastIndexOf(")")+1);
    hold_res['offset_x'] = ss.split(' ')[3]
    hold_res['offset_y'] = ss.split(' ')[4]
    hold_res['blur_radius'] = ss.split(' ')[5]
    hold_res['spread_radius'] = ss.split(' ')[6]
    return(hold_res)
    }
```

**HTML**:

```
<img id='my_img' src='https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/988775660163252226/XpgonN0X_400x400.jpg'>
```

[image]

**CSS**

```
img {
  box-shadow: 10px 20px 30px 40px #555;
}
```

**Usage**:

```
pick_apart('my_img')
```

**Result**:

```
{
    "color": "rgb(85, 85, 85)",
    "offset_x": "10px",
    "offset_y": "20px",
    "blur_radius": "30px",
    "spread_radius": "40px"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Its unfortunate there is no easier way to accomplish this.